# create sql server temp table in MS access passthru

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, pass-through

I have created an access query with a 3 field output of approx 700 records that I would like to use as an input to a passthru query to SQL server.

I have tested the process entirely in SQL server, and it works fine, but when I try to run the same code in a passtrhu, I get an error

> Pass-through query with returnrecords  property set to yes did not
>   return any records.

Here is the first few lines of the query:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#marktmp1') is not null drop table #marktmp1
create table #marktmp1
(Cid bigint,
Ccd varchar(6),
Ciss int);
/*
Insert into #marktmp1
values
(5110029175,    'SPO',  17),
(5110029722,    'SPO',  17),
(5110035139,    'SPO',  17);
```

I just copy/past the output of the first query into the list above

At the end of the list of records, I try to join the `#marktmp1` table to existing tables.

We are on Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm guessing you never do a select or return a result set in any other way (like calling a stored procedure). If that's the case, check the **IMPORTANT** note in this answer:

[how-to-create-temp-tables-in-sql-server-via-ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16841173/how-to-create-temp-tables-in-sql-server-via-ms-access/16844765#16844765)

Note, also check Gord Thompson's answer right after mine and make sure you won't have trouble with that.

Comment: The rest of the query joins to about 15 other tables and I do want to return a result in a select query. It is actually 2 select queries that I union together.  I wanted both to use the records that I am trying to load to the temp table. They were very long, so I ommitted it

Comment: Just to be certain here, you're using local temp tables, and you don't touch the temp table outside of your TSQL script. And when you run the script with the same data from SQL Server, it works correctly, and it does in fact return data? Are you able to convert the temp tables to real tables, just to see if it works?

Comment: I am really not that experienced.  However, the only temp table I am referring to is the one I create in the script above.  And yes - when I run the full script entirely within SQL server, it does return data.  I don't think I have permissions to create real tables.  However, I have selected  * from the temp table I created, and the records I inserted were returned

Comment: I think you're going to have to post the whole script. You can omit most of the inserts; just include the first and last values.

Comment: Oh, also, you might get that statement via a Debug.Print statement that prints the actual query text. Just trying to make sure the query you post is in fact the query that's being run.

Comment: I rewrote the query and am going to try and place it in 2 pieces:

Comment: the full query is too long by over 10,000 characters to fir in a comment

Comment: Sorry, distracted by work. Is it possible to put this into a stored proc? I wonder if Access isn't sending the whole query. It looks fine to me, just really big.

Comment: I have never done a stored proc before...not sure if my ID would allow it, but I could ask the owner to load it if I could create it.  Would the concept be to call the stored proc from the access passthrough?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly right. See that other answer I referenced for an example. You'll have to use SQL Server syntax, rather than DB2. Check the docs or Google for examples.

Comment: ok - I can give that a try, but I will need some quidance, such as: which pats (or all) of the query should go to the stred proc?  Also, will I need to use VBA?  If so, I have NEVER done that.

Comment: Oh you're not calling the pass-through via VBA code? If not, then you can't really pass parameters to your stored proc. Doesn't look like your uses any though, so you can probably just had code the SP call. Something like `exec dbo.SomeProcedureName`.

Comment: So would I just put the entire query in a stored procedure? then put an exec statement like the example above in the passthrough?

Comment: Yep. Exactly. Give that a try if you can.

Comment: Another thing you can do is take an ODBC trace and see exactly what Access is sending to SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks Brian.  I found a few "flaws" in the selection criteria of the query.  When I get those worked out, I will get back to creating a stored proc for this.  I may post back to this thread if I need any assistance.  I am very novice at this stuff

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution:  add `SET NOCOUNT ON` as the first command in the pass thru.

What is happening is when you insert records to the `#temp` table, SQL server responds with `### Record(s) affected.`  Access sees this message and interprets it as completion of the query, yet finds no rows returned.  This is why you get

> Pass-through query with returnrecords property set to yes did not
>   return any records

`SET NOCOUNT ON` turns off those information messages, and access will then wait for the final `SELECT` to occur.